# Undefined symbol error when accessing an extern bool

Tags: c++

I have `driver.h` which contains:

```
namespace org::lib{
  extern bool masterBool;
}
```

And a `library.h` which contains an anonymous namespace that defines `masterBool`:

```
namespace {
    bool masterBool = false;
    std::string otherFunction(){ 
        //....
    }
}
```

My `driver.cpp` which calls the `otherFunction()` and `masterBool`:

```
#include driver.h
#include library.h

namespace org::lib{

 void function(){
     otherFunction();
     if (masterBool){
        //.....
     }
 }
}
```

Upon compiling, I'm getting a undefined symbol: `org::lib::masterBool` in my `driver.cpp`. However, `otherFunction()` call did not such an error, even though they are both defined in the anonymous namespace of `library.h`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that anonymous namespace somehow wrapped into a `namespace org::lib`?

Comment: Where are you defining `bool org::lib::masterBool`?

Comment: @UnholySheep, yes it is, forgot to update my code, updated now.

Comment: The member of the anonymous namespace and the member of `org::lib` are two different variables.  You need to define the variable in the same namespace as its declaration.

Comment: @NathanOliver just updated the question, the anonymous namespace exists under an outer namespace of org::lib

Comment: @TedLyngmo i'm defining it in library.h

Comment: Why are you making it this complicated? Why do you have an extern declaration of `masterBool` in one header and a translation unit specific version in another header? Define it in `driver.cpp` and nowhere else - if it's supposed to be the same `bool`.

Comment: `namespace {` [anonymous namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces). Effectively makes everything in it `static`, This can put it at odds with `extern`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo masterBool needs to be defined in other cpp files as well.

Comment: @user1008636 Is `masterBool` supposed to be referring to the _same_ variable everywhere - or different variables with the same name?

Comment: @user4581301 so i cannot put the definition of masterBool into an anonymous namespace ?

Comment: @user1008636 Why would you want to?   The point of an anonymous namespace is to make a symbol unlinkable.

Comment: `namespace {` ... but why?

Comment: Can't say I've ever tried, but even if we eliminate the complexity of having other files we wind up with this: https://godbolt.org/z/dEE7Y8TnG . Note the `bool org::lib::{anonymous}::masterBool` vs the `bool org::lib::masterBool` in the error messages.. Cleary they are seen as different variables.

Comment: "_masterBool needs to be defined in other cpp files as well._": Every non-`inline` variable or function can have only one definition. It can't have multiple definitions in multiple translation units. What is the reason that you assume you need that?

Comment: Someone better with the nitty-gritty details of the language can provide a really interesting answer on the "Why" and drop Standard quotes, but me, I just learned something new about C++, so +1.

Comment: For completeness, here's the output from the big 3 compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/c4GG9YcGr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

`::org::lib::masterBool` is not the **same** variable as `::(unnamed)::masterBool` and is never defined.  (They wouldn't be the same even if the unnamed namespace appeared inside `org::lib`.)  There aren't two `otherFunction`s (in any one translation unit—see below), so that problem can't occur there.

More generally, [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61112742/8586227) [use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49588816/8586227) unnamed namespaces in header files; even the rare [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357564/8586227) are better served by `inline` variables (or some emulation of them prior to C++17).